# Printing struct field prints only the last element multiple times - C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct fileRep
{
    char *fileName;

    int index;
    int visited;
} fileRep;
```

My main function has this call to a function that creates an array of struct filRep:

```
fileRep  *allFiles = (fileRep*)malloc(MAX_LINES*sizeof(fileRep));
int i = linesToStruct(allFiles, fp);
```

This is the function:

```
int linesToStruct(fileRep* allFiles, FILE* fp)
{
char line[MAX_CHARS_LINE];
int i = 0;
while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp))
{

    fileRep file1 = createBasicFileStruct(line, i);
    allFiles[i] = file1;
    printf("%s is added\n", allFiles[i]);
    i++;
}
return i;
}
```

which calls this function:

```
fileRep createBasicFileStruct(char *line, int lineNumber)
{
char* name;
fileRep file1;
name = strtok(line, ":" );
file1.fileName = name;
file1.index = lineNumber;
file1.visited = 0;
return file1;
}
```

Now i try to iterate and print the fileName field of each fileRep struct i created:

```
int k = 0;
for(; k < i; k++)
{
    printf("File %d is %s\n", k, allFiles[k].fileName);
}
```

This results in this printing:

```
File 0 is file4
File 1 is file4
File 2 is file4
File 3 is file4
```

Now just some more info: The function lineToStruct has an internal test print, which prints:

```
file1.h is added
file2.h is added
file3.h is added
file4.h is added
```

Meaning it does add the files.

I am new to C and i am having trouble getting the pointer and array correlation, 
Why allFiles[0] is NULL? How do i set it to iterate properly?

Comment: _Now Let's assume that the function linesToStruct files allFiles nicely. it returns i which is the number of elements it added._ We can not assume that without seeing the code ;)

Comment: edited my question

Comment: Great, and now please show us the `createBasicFileStruct` function LOL ;) where are you assigning the string to the member `filename`?

Comment: Shouldn't this `allFiles[i].fileName)` be `allFiles[k].fileName)`?

Comment: Aaah, the common `strtok())` trap, which I already smelled when reading "*... prints **only the last** element ....*" :-)

Comment: alk - thanks, this was a typo but it did not solve it, it now prints the last element:

Comment: is it that strtok moved my pointer? how do i take it back :)

Comment: `strtok` returns a ***pointer*** (in)to `line`. It's the ***same*** memory on ***each*** iteration, namely the memory of 'line`.

Comment: Alright then, why is it related to my problem? line is just the line i am reading from a text file argument, i am parsing it to the name and create a struct regardless with that name.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger to trace the code while inspecting all variables to learn what is really going on.

Comment: "*line is just the line i am reading from a text file*", no it isn't, it is a variable, which gets "*filled*" by what was read. It's the same variable on each iteration.

Comment: Think twice: What exactly does the code store in `file1.fileName`?

Comment: I dont seem to get it :(

Comment: Answer this question: "*What exactly does the code store in `file1.fileName`?*" and become enlightened. ;-)

Comment: Actually, when adding this print message after file1.fileName = name; i get that each iteration prints a different file like i wanted it to.. so i think that is fine

Comment: You still did not answer the question.

Comment: I would really love it if you enlight me with an answer, i just don't get it. If i have to guess, it prints the files fileName of file1 just given by function createBasicFileStruct which returns a new fileRep struct. By the way this was solved by changing line to strdup(line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of `line` are replaced on each iteration of `fgets` in the function `linesToStruct`, you can pass a duplicate of the string (you can use `strdup(line)` for this) instead of `line`.

Or better yet (as suggested by @alk), pass `line` and then duplicate the tokenized string inside `createBasicFileStruct` if you don't need the rest of tokens:

```
name = strtok(line, ":" );
file1.fileName = strdup(name);
```

In this way you need less space.

Don't forget to `free` all those strings at the end.

Comment: I don't see the memory leak. I don't even see any `[m/c/re]alloc()`, in fact.

Comment: Notice my print inside function linesToStruct, it does show that it gets a new name every iteration..

Comment: @EF:  `fileRep  *allFiles = (fileRep*)malloc(MAX_LINES*sizeof(fileRep));`

Comment: It is not all of the code, there is a free(allFiles); line

Comment: @AlterMann: Uh, if `allFiles` is allocated by `malloc()`, modifying `allFiles[n]` is perfectly OK, and not a memory leak in any way, shape or form.

Comment: @EOF: oops, you are right, they are pointers not elements, I didn't see the `typedef`. Edited thanks ;)

Comment: Like this?         fileRep file1 = createBasicFileStruct(strdup(line), i);

Comment: @Eyzuky: Yes, try it.

Comment: Duplicating the buffer to be tokenised instead of the tokenisation's result is a ...well ... unconventional way to solve this.

Comment: Wow alter mann that actually did the trick!!!

Comment: @alk, `free` doesn't care about multiple `NUL` (`\0`) terminations in the string, isn't it?

Comment: @Eyzuky, I know hahaha, don't forget to free the `filename` member when no longer needed.

Comment: @AlterMann , a little noobish question - why do i need to free it if i did not call malloc for it? and also, why won't it be needed? I will need it to be a field in my struct for later in my code

Comment: @Eyzuky, `strdup` reserves space using `malloc`: _The strdup() function shall return a pointer to a new string, which is a duplicate of the string pointed to by s1. The returned pointer can be passed to free()._

Comment: @AlterMann thanks, you the man (of alter)

Comment: So is it line or fileName that i should free? because i am giving line to strdup

Comment: You need to free the member `filename` of each element of the array (maybe in a loop) when you no longer need those strings (not before).

Comment: @Eyzuky, you have an edit

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
int k = 0;
for(; k < i; k++)
{
    printf("File %d is %s\n", k, allFiles[i].fileName);
}
```

Shouldn't this be:

```
int k = 0;
for(; k < i; k++)
{
    printf("File %d is %s\n", k, allFiles[k].fileName);
}
```

??

Comment: Thanks, i already edited the question, it was a typo but it also does not solve the problem, it still prints the last file only multiple times